# Add the ability to feature badges (and other Stack Overflow content) on Developer Story

Tags: feature-request, badges, developer-story

Currently the only Stack Overflow related thing you can feature on your Developer Story is an answer.

Stack Overflow is so much more. I think you should be able to feature badges, questions you asked, documentation you wrote, groups you've created, etc., etc.

Comment: If you want a new feature, it's generally better to give more of a reason than "it would be neat" :).

Comment: By the way, the Teams feature has been shuttered for a couple weeks now.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Good idea. We're definitely going to expand the types of SO content you can include on your Dev Story.**

While we want the dev story to ensure that developers can show off whatever they're proud of - whether or not it's on SO - we definitely want those who *do* participate actively here to have easy ways to include their achievements.

And I'd guess all of the specific ideas you mention are likely to get added, probably not too long after V1 ships:

- **Badges** are a no-brainer, and we'd like to see it suggest the most valuable ones, or those that really highlight a proficiency (like gold badges, most tag badges, etc.).
- **Questions** make sense too.  Some questions help highlight the complexity of the problems you work on, or how well you can frame up a problem.
- **Docs** contributions will be added for sure. (There are a bunch of places we need to more fully integrate them.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why having a badge in something should be considered a point of pride, something you want to show off. I'm not sure I'd want to be hired by someone who sees three "Famous Question" gold badges on your CV and says, "yep, this guy's definitely an expert!"

I can understand wanting to put questions and answers that you're proud of on your "Developer's Story". But why badges? They *don't mean anything*. Even "Great Question/Answer" is far less important of a milestone to an employer than the specific question/answer behind it.

We have enough badge chasers around as is. We don't need to encourage this practice.

Also, documentation doesn't belong to you. It can be edited by anyone at any time for any reason. So showing it off is not an especially useful practice.

Comment: When I read the question, I was thinking of tag badges. You're right, it doesn't make much sense to show off the other types of badges, but having a gold tag badge does arguably suggest that you are at least familiar with the topic. (And now the question has changed since I first read it, which explains where your reference to documentation came from.)

Comment: Hey, I'm really proud of my `Unsung Hero` badge, okay?

Comment: @CodyGray: `Generalist` is not a proper tag badge but still a function of tag score, so it might be the exception that proves your rule.  And yes, I'm rather proud of mine. :D

Comment: @NicolBolas the point of any *earned badge* is to convey a message: "this person met the criteria for this badge" aka "this person did something not everyone has done". In short "this person performed exceptionally", even if in some small way. They convey information and let us form a better opinion about the user who earned the badge - they are a bit more trustworthy, a bit more of an expert, a bit more involved than one of their peers without it. Some badges moreso than others.

Comment: @TylerH: "*In short "this person performed exceptionally", even if in some small way.*" Which should be irrelevant to an employer. Again, I wouldn't want to work for someone who cares about SO badges rather than the quality and content of your actual SO *work*.

Comment: @NicolBolas Wrong, an employer *should* care about someone who is capable of and/or willing to perform exceptional work. Because the badge they earned *here* might be insignificant is not a reason to forego extrapolation of the applicant's character; an unsung hero badge doesn't say much about their skill in programming but it does say that they probably have a good attitude and can commit to an ideal even if they experience difficulties, etc. If an employer or hiring manager only looks at what's on the paper and doesn't look any deeper, you probably don't want to work for them.

Comment: @TylerH: "*an unsung hero badge doesn't say much about their skill in programming but it does say that they probably have a good attitude and can commit to an ideal even if they experience difficulties, etc.*" Or it says that they're just a badge hunter. Unreliable information is *unreliable*.

Comment: @NicolBolas Hunting badges still requires you to meet the criteria. Whether you meet it organically or as a goal is largely irrelevant. A great answer badge is still an indicator of a great answer. A generalist badge is still an indicator of a great breadth of knowledge. Et cetera. Besides, the plethora of other information available to a recruiter or hiring manager (namely, talking to the potential employee) is more important. Extra information like earned badges is just *extra*. Surely you wouldn't make a decision to hire someone *solely because they had earned a badge on a website*!

Comment: Nicol, did a badge hurt you as a child?